# Share live photo with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, share, phlivephoto

I generate a live photo from a couple of images and get a `PHLivePhoto` object in the end. Now I want to share that photo via a `UIActivityViewController`. The initialisation looks as follows:

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, livePhoto], applicationActivities: nil)
```

When I send a message with that livePhoto attached it only sends a static image. Same for saving it to the camera roll.

How can I share the actual live photo, so that the user can replay it when he/she saves it to the camera roll for example?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do like that with UIActivityViewController

UIActivityViewController class is mainly created for copying items to the pasteboard and share.

For more info read below link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/

Comment: thanks for your answer! When you share a photo within the photos app it uses a controller similar to an UIActivityViewController and you can send a live photo with it. That's why I thought it may be possible.

Comment: Yes,  I also thought it may be possible